# Geometric meaning of the chi-square "measure of association"

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, convex-geometry

In Statistics, there's a standard [test of independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) of two random variables taking values in finite sets $I,J$. It relies on the computation of $\chi$-square statistics, 
$$
\chi^2:=\sum_{(i,j)\in I\times J}\frac{(p_{ij}-p_{i+}p_{+j})^2}{p_{i+}p_{+j}}.
$$
Here $p_{i,j}$ is the probability that the two variables take values $i,j$ (or, in the statistical context, the observed frequency of the corresponding outcomes), and $p_{i+}=\sum_jp_{ij}$, $p_{+j}=\sum_ip_{ij}$. The idea behind the test is that under the null-hypothesis that the variables are independent, and under certain natural assumptions, this will approximately follow $\chi^2$ distribution, and  thus too large a value allows one to reject the null-hypothesis (and, conversely, two small a value is sometimes used as a hint at rigged data).

What I'm looking for is a geometric insight into the above quantity. We have a function on the set of $|J|$-tuples of $|I|$-dimensional vectors in the positive cone which sum to a probability vector. This function vanishes iff all the vectors are proportional. I would like to understand its geometric meaning: e. g., is it possible to estimate it accurately from above and below with some standard coordinate-free quantities, like vector (bivector etc.) norms?

I am most interested in the case $|J|=2$. Note that if $|I|=|J|=2$, we have $$
\chi^2=\frac{(p_{11}p_{22}-p_{12}p_{21})^2}{p_{1+}p_{2+}p_{+1}p_{+2}},
$$
so that it's just the cross product, normalised by factors that get small when vectors are very unequal in length and/or very "degenerate" (both close to one of the axes). Are there any identities or estimates of this in more general case?

Comment: I would expect a nice geometric interpretation if we had some nice geometric symmetry, but the only symmetry I see here is from renumbering the outcomes.

Comment: @MattF. : What do you mean by "renumbering" in this situation?